# Cannot query Hive remote server

Tags: hive

I am trying to query on remote hive `server2`. The connection was successful but I am not able to query.

The screen freezes for long time.

I am not sure the query request went to hive server.

[image: remote hive]

Comment: 0
down vote
Is the hive thriftserver running? Is the hive metastore running?

Comment: Yes thriftserver & hive metastore running on remote machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I started Hive server2 and trying to connect through HIVE CLI

Actually HIVE CLI is for hiveserver1, 
Beeline is correct one for hiveserver2